# Alignment issues with flow document reader - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, blend, flowdocument

I am trying to load a .txt file onto a flow document reader, but the columns are not correctly aligned, i.e. there is no uniform spacing between the columns. How can I get the same alignment in the flow document, as it is present in the notepad file. I mean I would like to retain the spacing between consecutive words in a given line, as it is present in the original .txt file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a [Monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) to achieve that.

```
<FlowDocument FontFamily="Courier"/>
```

Comment: "Courier" didn't work, but I tried "Lucida Console", now the alignment is proper. Thanks a lot! :-)